# Interrupts in 8051 Comparator

Tags: microcontroller, interrupt, 8051

I am working Silicon Labs C8051F120.
        Below is the code I am using for Comparator.
        By right when I decrease the power supply I should get an interrupt.
        But I am not getting the interrupt.
        I am doubting the initialization routine.
        Normal voltage is 5V. When voltage is decreased to 4.2V, I should get Comparator 1 interrupt. When voltage is decreased to 3.V, I should get Comparator 0 interrupt.
        Also I am confused why there are two ways by which Comparator Interrupt can be enabled:
        1)By CPTT0MD/CPT1MD: Comparator0/Comparator1 Mode Selection
        2) EIE1: Extended Interrupt Enable 1
    Which one to use when and why?

```
    #define COMPARATOR_SETTLE 30

void Comp0_Init()
{

      char SFRPAGE_SAVE = SFRPAGE;
      SFRPAGE = CPT0_PAGE;
      CPT0CN = 0x83;                      // Comparator0 enabled       // 20 mV Negative hysteresis
      Delay_us (COMPARATOR_SETTLE);   // Allow CP0 output to settle for 20 us
      CP0RIF = 0;
      CP0FIF = 0;
      CPT0MD = 0x10;
      EIE1 |= 0x10;
      SFRPAGE = SFRPAGE_SAVE;

}

void Comp0_ISR(void) interrupt (10) 
{

      CP0FIF = 0;
      comp_flag = 1;

}

void Comp1_Init()
{

      char SFRPAGE_SAVE = SFRPAGE;
      SFRPAGE = CPT1_PAGE;
      CPT1CN = 0x83;                      // Comparator0 enabled       // 20 mV Negative hysteresis
      Delay_us (COMPARATOR_SETTLE);   // Allow CP0 output to settle for 20 us
      CP1RIF = 0;
      CP1FIF = 0;
      CPT1MD = 0x10;
      EIE1 |= 0x40;
      SFRPAGE = SFRPAGE_SAVE;

}

void Comp1_ISR(void) interrupt (12) 
{

      CP1FIF = 0;
      comp_flag = 2;

}
```

Comment: Is the global interrupt flag set?

Comment: yes I have enabled the global interrupt in main loop, EA = 1.